# Работа с rebase -i

Tags: git, git-rebase

Пытаюсь сделать squash, хочу в ветке master соединить первый и последний коммит, после rebase -i ставлю первый коммит, далее у него стоит параметр pick, после всем коммитам ставлю параметр squash, при это почему-то проект приводится к состоянию именно первого коммита. Может я что-то не правильно понял, но ведь мы делаем операцию squash чтобы соединить все коммиты в один с учетом всех изменений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. при *соединении* (*squash*) «в одну кучу» изменений, произведённых в двух (и более) коммитах, создаётся новый коммит.
2. *соединяемые* (*squashed*) коммиты должны идти один за другим.
3. в списке коммитов, который открывается для редактирования после ввода команды `rebase -i`, коммиты приведены в обратной хронологической последовательности (как и, например, при вводе команды `log`): самый верхний — самый «младший», следующий — его «родитель» и т.д.
4. в первом столбце указано действие — `pick` (взять как есть).
5. если это действие заменить на `squash` (можно сократить вплоть до одной буквы — `s`), то изменения, внесённые данным коммитом, будут *соединены* с изменениями, внесёнными его «потомком», т.е., коммитом, идущим **выше** по списку.

   вот в этом примере будут *соединены* `коммит3` и `коммит2`:

   ```
   pick   хэш3 коммит3
   squash хэш2 коммит2
   pick   хэш1 коммит1
   ```

   а в этом — `коммит2` и `коммит1` (*):

   ```
   pick   хэш3 коммит3
   pick   хэш2 коммит2
   squash хэш1 коммит1
   ```

   а в этом — все три коммита:

   ```
   pick   хэш3 коммит3
   squash хэш2 коммит2
   squash хэш1 коммит1
   ```
6. отсюда следствие: для самого верхнего в списке коммита (самого «молодого») нельзя указать действие `squash` (при попытке совершить такую операцию получите ошибку: «Cannot 'squash' without a previous commit»).

---

(*) — обратите внимание: в данном случае после завершения операции хэш «незатронутого» коммита (`хэш3`) будет изменён — ведь его «родителем» будет уже совсем другой коммит.

Comment: если были смерженые ветки, всплывают конфликты, решив их все, git rebase будет завершен.